# Gradle : Create new instance with ObjectFactory without @Inject

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am writing a gradle plugin (using gradle `5.6.3`) and I need to create an instance of a model class in my `Plugin` class.

As per [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html), I am using [ObjectFactory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/model/ObjectFactory.html) to create instances. Below is an example code:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = rootProject.services.get(ObjectFactory)
objectFactory.newInstance(class, args)
```

When I execute this script, I get an error saying `The constructor for class <MyClass> should be annotated with @Inject`. Now, this class is present in one of the libraries which I don't own, so I can't add the annotation for the constructor. In that case, is there any way to instantiate the class?

Comment: What's the library?

Comment: you can also obtain `ObjectFactory` via : `ObjectFactory objectFactory = project.getObjects();`. does that help?

Comment: @Eugene it does :)